# Google Plus Not validating page properly and showing red triangle error after clicked

Tags: google-plus-one

I am trying to integrate google-plus-one into a website...but after clicking the google plus button it just shows the pink triangle error (with the exception of at the top level, its for all sub pages).

Here's an example: http://www.bigfunny.com/watch/15/i-beweave-hair-salon

If anybody knows why it wont work or validate properly in the google plus world...I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: fyi google plusing http://www.bigfunny.com will work, so for some reason the http://www.bigfunny.com/watch/15/i-beweave-hair-salon link gives the google plus an error, would love find a tool like facebook has that can show whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

So I have broken that page down to the bare minimum and still get the error you are getting. Ive searched around and it seems like the error goes away for most webmasters after a few days. I would check out Google Webmaster settings and see what happens over the weekend.

I was unable to get it working on a detail page but the root and /about/ page things worked.

I would also just test it out on the link below:

[Google Plus Button](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/)